# print multiple copies of a document Applescripting a printer's app

Tags: macos, printing, applescript

I'm trying to automate some hard printing.

I already can print one copy of a document accessing the printer's app like this :

```
tell application "hp LaserJet 2300 series (BDB806)" --my printer's app, could be any other model
    print myFile
end tell
```

This snippet works.

But it becomes tricky when I try to print multiple copies. According to the printer's app dictionnary, I should be able to achieve it by doing :

```
tell application "hp LaserJet 2300 series (BDB806)"
    print myFile with properties {copies:n} -- n being an integer
end tell
```

But this doesn't work.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens the same to me with this code:

```
set d to ((path to home folder) as string) & "Desktop:" & "untitled.txt"
set n to 3
tell application "EPSON WP-4595 Series"
    print d with properties {copies:n}
end tell
```

Only one copy is printed.

As far as I know nothing is wrong with the code, maybe something is wrong with AppleScript..

Not very elegant but you could always do

```
...
    repeat n times
        print d
    end repeat
```

Comment: @ Paolo Thanks, might be a bug in AppleScript then, as I've read about similar problems with that `{copies:n}`parameter. I had used a repeat statement as an unfinished solution. The problem is that printing a great number of copies is slow as the printer takes each copy as a separate job.

Comment: you can also open the document with it's application, and do some GUI scripting to open the print dialog, set copies, print. But it's a very bad approach.